# How can I animate an image bluring?

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, blur

I would like to animate the bluring on image in JQuery

I have this image :

```
<img id="right" class="vote" src="css/images/no.png" alt="no button" onclick="vote(0)">
```

And I would like to do become this image more blur during 1 seconde.

Somethings like this :

```
$("#right").animate({"-webkit-filter":"blur(30px)"},1000);
```

But this don't works.

I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211943/jquery-should-blur-fullscreen-background-image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781486/jquery-how-to-adjust-css-filter-blur

Comment: Thank's, but i would like animate with JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommended the Richa's pure css solution, but here's the pure jQuery solution if you really want to:

```
   $("#right").animate({blurRadius: 30}, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function() {
            $(this).css({
                "-webkit-filter": "blur("+this.blurRadius+"px)"
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to blur image on hover using just CSS.
Take a look at **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3asZC/1009/)**

```
#css-filter-blur:hover { -webkit-filter: blur(2px); filter: url(#blur-effect-1); }
```

***UPdate***

Something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3asZC/1010/)

Comment: But with JQuery ? Because I can do this with an CSS animation

Comment: @ioh have a look at updated fiddle. Is this what you are looking for